# R column mean by factor

Tags: r

I have data set like this

```
data
name v1  v2  v3  v4  v5
a    1   2   7   9   3
b    3   8   6   4   8
c    2   5   0   1   9
a    6   0   6   2   1
c    3   9   4   7   5
```

`name` is a factor variable. I want to calculate mean of `v2,v3,v4,v5` by the factor `data$name`. I used following command, but it did not work.

```
tapply(data[,3:6],data$name,mean)
```

Now, I used following code

```
newdata<-0
for (name in unique(data$name)){
    rowIndex <- which(data$name == name)
    result <- colMeans(data[rowIndex,])
    newdata[name,]<-result
}
```

The required result is obtained. But I want to know if there is some sleek method to do this.

Comment: Try `library(data.table); setDT(data)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = name, .SDcols = paste0("v", 2:5)]` (haven't tested)

Comment: Your sample code doesn't work. Can you post your expected output?

Comment: I have added the expected result in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another way

```
library(data.table)
cols <- paste0("v", 2:5) # set the columns you want to operate on
setDT(data)[, Sums := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = cols]
data[, list(Means = sum(Sums)/(.N*length(cols))), by = name]
##    name Means
## 1:    a  3.75
## 2:    b  6.50
## 3:    c  5.00
```

**Edit**

Per @Aruns suggestion, that would be probably much better

```
setDT(data)[, mean(c(v2,v3,v4,v5)), by=name]
##    name   V1
## 1:    a 3.75
## 2:    b 6.50
## 3:    c 5.00
```

Or per @Anandas suggestion

```
library(reshape2)
melt(setDT(data), id.vars = "name", measure.vars = cols)[, mean(value), by = name]
##    name   V1
## 1:    a 3.75
## 2:    b 6.50
## 3:    c 5.00
```

Comment: I don't know the tradeoffs between `.SD` and `melt`, but `melt(setDT(data), id.vars = "name", measure.vars = cols)[, mean(value), by = name]` perhaps?

Comment: Or `data[, mean(c(v2,v3,v4,v5)), by=name]`. If there're more columns, we can just construct an expression and evaluate it.

Comment: @Arun, that is neat. I was trying to do this, but had problems with the column names. Probably because I used `paste` and they became quoted

Answer (score 4):

According to the expected result showed:

ie. `The expected result for factor a is a (2+7+9+3)+(0+6+2+1)/8`

```
sapply(split(dat[,-(1:2)], dat$name), function(x) sum(x)/prod(dim(x)))
#  a    b    c 
# 3.75 6.50 5.00
```

Or

```
tapply(rowMeans(dat[,-(1:2)]), dat[,1], sum)/table(dat[,1])
 #a    b    c 
 #3.75 6.50 5.00
```

Or

```
 m1 <- as.matrix(dat[,-c(1:2)])
 c(by(c(m1), dat[,1][row(m1)], FUN=mean))
 #  a    b    c 
 #3.75 6.50 5.00
```

Or the methods suggested by @Ananda Mahto

```
  tapply(unlist(dat[-c(1, 2)]), rep(dat$name, 4), mean)
  #   a    b    c 
  #3.75 6.50 5.00 

  tapply(stack(dat, select = paste0("v", 2:5))$values, rep(dat$name, 4), mean)
  #  a    b    c 
  #3.75 6.50 5.00
```

Comment: @David Arenburg Thanks I gave +1 for you for the data.table code.  I guess `4` is the ncol(data), right?

Comment: Yeah.. It's not so general as yours. I'm thinking to predefine the column names in the beginning and then make it more general. Edited it respectively

Comment: Where's `stack` and `unlist`? Don't make them feel marginalized :-)

Comment: @Ananda Mahto  I was thinking about trying `unlist`, but somehow, I ended up with `c`. :-)

Comment: @Ananda Mahto  Thanks for the suggestion, That was one of the methods I tried using `by`

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with a combination of the dplyr and tidyr packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% gather(name, value, v2:v5) %>%
    group_by(name) %>% summarize(average=mean(value))
#   name average
# 1    a    3.75
# 2    b    6.50
# 3    c    5.00
```

---

This works because `gather` brings the `v2:v5` columns together into a single column where they can be intuitively grouped:

```
data %>% gather(name, value, v2:v5)
#    name v1 name value
# 1     a  1   v2     2
# 2     b  3   v2     8
# 3     c  2   v2     5
# 4     a  6   v2     0
# 5     c  3   v2     9
# 6     a  1   v3     7
# ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: original answer was not giving the correct result. This seems to work OK (select(-variable) avoids having an extra column, but otherwise is not needed)

Using the dplyr and reshape2 packages:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
 select(-v1) %>%
 melt %>% 
 group_by(name) %>% 
 select(-variable) %>% 
 summarise_each(funs(mean))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
# 
#   name value
# 1    a  3.75
# 2    b  6.50
# 3    c  5.00
```

Comment: That won't give the desired output

Comment: Oh, god. You are right @DavidArenburg. Must be more carefully (again...) next time.

Comment: OK, have modified the answer and now it works. However, not sure how *sleek* this is...

Comment: Thanks for the edits @DavidArenburg, this looks much better now.

Answer (score 1):

All good answers, but I just want to add this one:

```
data <- data.frame(name=as.factor(c("a","b","c","a","c")),
                   v1=c(1,3,2,6,3),
                   v2=c(2,8,5,0,9),
                   v3=c(7,6,0,6,4),
                   v4=c(9,4,1,2,7),
                   v5=c(3,8,9,1,5))

u.id <- unique(data$name)
newdata <- t(sapply(unique(u.id),function(c.id){
    colMeans(data[data$name == c.id,-1])
}))
rownames(newdata) <- u.id

newdata

  v1  v2  v3  v4 v5
a 3.5  1 6.5 5.5  2
b 3.0  8 6.0 4.0  8
c 2.5  7 2.0 4.0  7
```